# Start a program, take automatic screenshot when its GUI has instantiated, then close program

Tags: linux, command-line, screenshot

This is my problem: I have a shell script, where I use `gitk --all .` for a graphical representation of a git repository. I would like this script to run unattended, and instead of starting gitk in GUI mode where it waits for the user to close it down, I'd like to somehow:

- Start the `gitk` window
- When it has instantiated its GUI/window, take automatic screenshot of its window
- Once the screenshot has been captured, close `gitk`

I would imagine, instead of calling

```
gitk --all .
```

... in my `bash` script, I would otherwise call something like this pseudocode:

```
my_scrshot_cmd --command "gitk --all ." --file myrandomfilename.png
```

Is this possible to do on Linux - and if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do something like this

```
gitk --all . &         # You run the gitk and go forward meanwhile
PidOfLastCommand=$!    # You need to remember the PID after
sleep 30s              # Change this value with the needed one... 
import screenshot.png  # From Imagemagick it saves the screenshot
kill $PidOfLastCommand # Let's we kill gitk

echo "### Just DONE ###"
```

**Notes:**

- It requires Imagemagick installed (for `import`, but you can change the command with [the one you prefer](https://askubuntu.com/q/194427/196535)).
- You need to wait enough time in `sleep` ... do some test and take a cosy value (you have to be sure it did its work)

Comment: Many thanks for that, @Hastur - I indeed have Imagemagick, so this will do the trick for me; accepted for now... Cheers!